# How to partially slice data based on a condition in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset, where I want to remove 60% of the data that corresponds to specific class. So, I can do something like this:

```
dataset %>% filter(Outcome=="diabetes") %>% slice(-seq(0.4 * n()))
```

However, this first filters only for the parts of dataset from which I wanna remove entries, and then slices that. Though, I want my end result to be the original dataset except 60% of the data removed that matches `Outcome=="diabetes"`. How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sample_frac` to do this: Get 60% per group:

```
mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl == 4) %>%
  sample_frac(0.6)

   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
2 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
3 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
4 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
5 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
6 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
7 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

Why did you accept it? I think it did not what you wanted? I leave my original answer, but I think you wanted this:

```
result <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  sample_frac(ifelse(cyl == 4, 0.6, 1))

# A tibble: 15 x 11
# Groups:   cyl [3]
     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08  2.2   19.5     1     1     4     1
 2  27.3     4  79      66  4.08  1.94  18.9     1     1     4     1
 3  21.5     4 120.     97  3.7   2.46  20.0     1     0     3     1
 4  22.8     4 108      93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
 5  24.4     4 147.     62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
 6  22.8     4 141.     95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
 7  26       4 120.     91  4.43  2.14  16.7     0     1     5     2
 8  21.4     4 121     109  4.11  2.78  18.6     1     1     4     2
 9  30.4     4  95.1   113  3.77  1.51  16.9     1     1     5     2
10  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93  1.62  18.5     1     1     4     2
11  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22  1.84  19.9     1     1     4     1
12  17.8     6 168.    123  3.92  3.44  18.9     1     0     4     4
13  15       8 301     335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8
14  14.7     8 440     230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4
15  18.7     8 360     175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
```

Comment: But, where is the rest of the data with cyl=6, or 8, etc? I want them to be combined. So, imagine you have this dataset, end result is the same dataset, except for the entries where cyl=4, 60% of them are remvoed, so if you had 100 with cyl=4, then end result is the same dataset, except there will be 40 entries with cyl=4.

Comment: why did you accept it? :-). I guess I got what you wanted.

Comment: I actually used your approach and combined with “rbind”, to form the data frame. With this approach I see that you remove 80% from all classes except 4? Am I right? This is not quite what I wanted, I wanted to remove only 60% from class 4 and not touch other classes.

Comment: Well you can play around with the numbers, but the solutions works fine. To leave everything else just use 1 in the else statement.